# Google Spreadsheet SUMIF aggregation - multiple strings in condition

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

How to use Google Spreadsheet `SUMIF` agregation function with more than one condition?

What I currently have is formula:
`=SUMIF( A1:A50, "match_this",B1:B50)`

But I want to improve it to have 2 conditions:
`=SUMIF( A1:A50, _ONE_OF_("match_this", "match_that"),B1:B50)`

Is there operand like my imaginary `_ONE_OF_` or what is the most simple, and correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by combining `sum` with `filter`. The `filter` can use several conditions, which may be joined by + (meaning OR), or by * (meaning AND). Example:

```
=sum(filter(B1:B50, (A1:A50 = "match_this") + (A1:A50 = "match_that")))
```

sums the entries in B1:B50 where A1:A50 is either of two things.

#### Notes

- There is [`sumifs`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en) but it joins conditions only as AND
- There is [`or`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en) but it's not supported by `sumif`
- The great flexibility of [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) is that it focuses on one thing: filtering a range by a condition. You can apply any function you want to the filtered results: sum, product, count, maximum, etc. Also, the condition can be expressed by any formula, not constrained by a rigid syntax of `sumif` and its relatives. For example, advanced string filtering can be done with [`regexmatch`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en).